# In MS Access, how can I get and echo userid in a MessageBox?

Tags: ms-access

Access 2007 - 2016, Microsoft Office ProPlus

Access and VBA novice, so please bear with :-)

Trying to get userid from system and then stick it in a message box.  Here is my prototype attempt (Macro)...

```
SetLocalVar
    Name theuser
  Expression = fOSUserName()

MessageBox
  Message "Hi there..." & theuser
  Beep No
  Type Information
  Title sayhi
```

fOUserName is a macro that I got from http://www.databasedev.co.uk/get_username_or_computername.html
I echoed this as a "Moodule" I called "getuser" in Access. Here is the code ...

```
Option Compare Database

Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
"GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function fOSUserName() As String
' Returns the network login name
  Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
  Dim strUserName As String
  strUserName = String$(254, 0)
  lngLen = 255
  lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
  If lngX <> 0 Then
    fOSUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1)
  Else
    fOSUserName = "NoMan"
  End If
End Function
```

No Error Msg.
Nothing in USysApplicationLog

I then tried to simply echo the value of a hardcoded variable called "testvar"....

```
SetLocalVar
    Name testvar
  Expression "foo"
```

I replaced "theuser" with "testvar" in the MessageBox piece, tried it, and that too failed.

Clearly I don't know to get messsagebox (in Access) to echo a variable and need help with that.

But I would also like any critique on the fOUserName function if possible.  Will this get me what I want ?  If not, any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Comment: The module code from above works for me.  Here is something to try --  In fOSUserName, right before   End Function,  add Debug.Print  fOSUserName.   Then run it and see what you get.  This will determine whether the problem is in the macro or in the module.

Comment: Why use macro? Why not just stick with VBA? An alternative to the API function is `Environ("USERNAME")`.

Comment: When I replace the "Message" with... ' "Hi there... " & Environ("USERNAME")' , I get ' "Hi there... " & Environ("USERNAME")'.  IOW, it just echoes the string, doesn't run the Environ macro.  I tried this before and got the same result.  I'm probably calling it wrong or something.

Answer (score 1):

Use expression preceded by equal sign to access the variable.

[image]

Comment: Like a charm !
Thanks Santosh .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VBA code then just type Msgbox and press ctrl+space bar to enable intellisense which would tell you what argument are required. I really don't know the specific name of arguments but I'll explain the first three that I use most oftenly.

Msgbox [arg1], [arg2] , [arg3]

**[arg1]** = Message to be displayed 
**[arg2]** = msgbox type. you specify if it is a yes/no dialog or simple msg box. For simple msgbox you can use vbInformation, vbCritical and others too to show different type of msgbox icon and the vbCritical is mostly used to capture errors and produces error(beep) sound too. 
**[arg3]** = Title of Msgbox

For your user case, you can use this msgbox

```
Msgbox "Hi there " & Environ("USERNAME"), vbInformation, "Greetings"
```

If you want it to appear every time the database is opened just create a vba module copy the above line of code in it and save it as "autoExec" and it will auto execute every time the database is opened.